# Transparent proxy - from port 80 to 443

Tags: c#, http, https, proxy, transparent

I'm trying to develop a transparent proxy which forwards unsecured http traffic from the clients as secured https traffic to the server, and back again.  To better illustrate my point, take a look at the following image.

[image: Rich Picture]

Let's suppose that for various reasons the clients will be using HTTP only, they can't use port 443 for HTTPS.  Since some servers don't accept traffic from port 80, my proxy needs to reroute them to port 443.  This is a possible scenario:

1. Receive data from client which are headed to port 80 towards www.google.com
2. Initialize connection with https://www.google.com to port 443 (Do the handshake and so on)
3. Encrypt data from client and send them to https://www.google.com to port 443.
4. Receive response from https://www.google.com, decrypt them and send them back to the client to port 80.

Since this is a transparent proxy, the clients (in my case lots of them) shouldn't need any extra configuration.  The network is already configured so that their traffic go through my node.  Currently my node simply reroutes the data and blocks some if they contain viruses.  This is done using [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) to get access to low networking layers but I'm willing to change my approach if it's too hard to be done using raw packets (mainly concerned about the handshake).

**What I've tried:**
Note: www.google.com could be any site on the web.  It's merely used as an example.

1. Iridium's suggestion.  This doesn't work for the reason that TcpListener only accepts a new connection if another application uses a TcpClient to connect to it.  Since this is a transparent proxy, it doesn't work.
2. Using HttpListener instead.  However, it seems that this doesn't work since it only accepts connections to my own IP (not www.google.com).
3. Using HttpListener as before but this time I'm forwarding packets to my own IP so that HttpListener accepts the connection.  For some reason, this doesn't seem to work (Inspected through wireshark and TCP SYN packets keep re-sending, not sure why or how to fix it).
4. Using SslStream to connect to https://www.google.com, then getting the contents from the raw packets received from the clients and writing them to the stream.  This doesn't work since SslStream handles TCP packets (Such as ACK or SYN) on its own.  The stream expects only Http requests.  Another reason why it doesn't work is because I can't read the contents of TCP packets from the stream, only the contents of HTTP responses (So the client is sat there waiting for an ACK).
5. Forwarding TCP packets from the client as they are to port 443 and from the server to port 80 (Since only HTTP requests and responses are encrypted with SSL, it wouldn't make a difference) and using the HttpRequest class to make all the http requests and responses (Since the class handles the handshake on its own).  This doesn't work because the ACKs are wrong on both sides.

What would be the best way to go into developing such a proxy?

Edit:  Is there ANY way that TcpListener or HttpListener can act as a transparent proxy? (Without configuration on the clients' computers).  When exactly does HttpListener recognize that a client is trying to connect?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem, but just in case you need SSL encryption/decryption of existing data, take a look at TElSSLClient and TElSSLServer classes in our SecureBlackbox ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php ) . They are transport-independent (your code provides a transport) and maybe you can use them instead of SSLStream.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because the client will also be waiting for ACK packets (Not just HTTP responses)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you need to read the encrypted data from the `SslStream`. If I'm reading your description correctly, you should simply need to:

- Wait for a client connection
- When a client connects, connect to the server
- Wrap the server connection's `NetworkStream` in an `SslStream` and `AuthenticateAsClient`
- Once authenticated, in parallel:

  - Read data from the client and write it to the `SslStream`
  - Read data from the `SslStream` and write it to the client

I don't see anywhere in this process that you'd need to see the encrypted data from the `SslStream`.

The following is a very basic sample (though completely untested):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 11180);
    var clientConnection = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    // When we get here, the client has connected, initiate the server connection
    var serverConnection = new TcpClient("your.server.name", 443);
    var serverStream = serverConnection.GetStream();
    var secureStream = new SslStream(serverStream);
    secureStream.AuthenticateAsClient("your.server.name");
    ConnectStreams(clientConnection.GetStream(), secureStream);
}

private static void ConnectStreams(Stream streamA, Stream streamB)
{
    ForwardStream(streamA, streamB, new byte[1024]);
    ForwardStream(streamB, streamA, new byte[1024]);
}

private static void ForwardStream(Stream source, Stream destination, byte[] buffer)
{
    source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, r => Forward(source, destination, r, buffer), null);
}

private static void Forward(Stream source, Stream destination, IAsyncResult asyncResult, byte[] buffer)
{
    var bytesRead = source.EndRead(asyncResult);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        destination.Close();
        return;
    }
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    ForwardStream(source, destination, buffer);
}
```

Comment: I receive TCP packets (Without an HTTP payload, such as ACKs) from the client.  SSLStream handles TCP packets on its own, so I can't forward the tcp packets received from the client because there would constantly be re-transmissions because of invalid ACKs.  Your suggestion (Which it's currentyl what's implemented) would work perfectly if SSLStream didn't handle TCP packets on its own.  Not sure if I explained this good enough.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm not using TcpClient to read data from the client.  I'm using raw sockets to read the data, which is why I'm also reading TCP packets from the client.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You're going to need to give some actual code in your question in order to get a decent answer then.

Comment: I've just read your sample.  I noticed the first argument of TcpListener which is IPAddress.Any.  Does that mean that it will read data that are headed to any address?  Also, does it know how to automatically accept connections through TCP? (When the SYN flag is set).  I'm going to do some tests, thank you for your help, I appreciate it : )

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` causes it to listen on all of the machine's IP addresses rather than a specific address.

Comment: With all this mention of SYN and ACK, I'm wondering if you're really understanding what's going on here - it is not possible to send TCP data using raw sockets in Windows, and using the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class and "raw sockets" are very different things.

Comment: I'm not using System.Net.Sockets, I'm actually using WinPcap to forward packets individually because I couldn't figure out another way (Since it's an anonymous proxy, the client shouldn't install an application for this).  The data pass through my proxy because of how the network is set up (My proxy is like a router, basically).  TcpListener doesn't seem to accept connections unless another application uses a TcpClient to connect to it.